# yum list subversion isn't work in Red Hat Enterprise 6

Tags: rhel, yum, subversion

I wanted list all svn versions available typing:

```
yum list subversion
```

but the command doesn't work.

[image]

It seems that the link isn't working, so If it's true.

Could you tell me how I can list all svn available?

Comment: Please replace the image with the corresponding text.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a problem with PUIAS_6_computational repo, you can disable this during the search for subversion with

```
# yum list subversion --disablerepo=PUIAS_6_computational
```

or permanently disable by adding "enabled=0" to the .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d or alternatively if the repo no longer exists delete the repo file. all these suggestion will remove the error.

It also looks like your system is not registered to redhat subscription manager, unless you have a local repository serving the Redhat repositories you will need to register the host with Redhat's subscription manager to get access to Redhat packages and updates.